# Multiple string selection with specific parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a multiple selection and modification on a column of dates. The dates are converted in string for other applications. 
Right now i want to select all dates that are in year 1900 using `df.loc[]`. 
Dates are in format mm/dd/yyyy (still strings tho)
So my try :

```
df.loc[df['Trade Date'][-4:]=='1900']=1
```

Raise this error :

> IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series key provided')
>   pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided

Is it possible ? 
Or do i have to iterate with a `df.get_value()`

Comment: try `df.loc[df['Trade Date'].str[-4:]=='1900']=1`

Comment: Genius! thx EdChum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to slice the string, to do this use `.str`:

```
df.loc[df['Trade Date'].str[-4:]=='1900']=1
```

depending on what you really intending to do it may make more sense to convert to datetime:

```
df['Trade Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Trade Date'])
```

then you can do:

```
df.loc[df['Trade Date'].dt.year == 1900]=1
```

using datetime makes more sense as numerical operations will just work whilst keeping the data as strings is not as easy to work with

Comment: I'll use the string, I am just doing comparison to categorize data

Comment: ahah i know how it works i was waiting for the end of the time limit to accept an answer